# Уничтожение созданных узлов из DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

**Такой вопрос:**
Если внутри функции создается DOM элемент на который не назначается родитель, то он сам уничтожается когда функция выполнилась или остается весеть в памяти?
если остается в памяти, то как его уничтожить?

```
function demoCreate(){
  var domNode = document.createElement("div");
  ...//здесь идет работа с ним 
  //уничтожется ли domNode после окончания выполнения этой функции???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае, когда созданный элемент находится в пределах одной функции и не был добавлен в DOM, и нет никаких ссылок на него из других объектов, то по окончании выполнения функции он будет стерт из памяти. Механизм стирания из памяти варьирует в зависимости от используемого браузера, но по идее он есть в каждом из них (Garbage Collection). Тоже касается, когда элемент удаляется из DOM, а также удаляются все его связи и указания на него.

delete функция в данном случае бесполезна.